# What does the -> (dash-greater-than arrow symbol) mean in a Python method signature?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a `->`, or dash-greater-than symbol at the end of a python method, and I'm not sure what it means. One might call it an arrow as well.

Here is the example:

```
@property
def get_foo(self) -> Foo:
    return self._foo
```

where `self._foo` is an instance of Foo.

My guess is that it is some kind of static type declaration, to tell the interpreter that `self._foo` is of type Foo. But when I tested this, if `self._foo` is not an instance of Foo, nothing unusual happens. Also, if `self._foo` is of a type other than Foo, let's say it was an `int`, then `type(SomeClass.get_foo())` returns `int`. So, what's the point of `-> Foo`?

This concept is hard to lookup because it is a symbol without a common name, and the term "arrow" is misleading.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is [function annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/). It can be use to attach additional information to the [arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#id31) or a [return values](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#id32) of functions. It is a useful way to say how a function must be used.
Functions annotations are stored in a function's `__annotations__` attribute.

[**Use Cases** (*From documentation*)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#id35)

- Providing typing information

  - Type checking
  - Let IDEs show what types a function expects and returns
  - Function overloading / generic functions
  - Foreign-language bridges
  - Adaptation
  - Predicate logic functions
  - Database query mapping
  - RPC parameter marshaling
- Other information

  - Documentation for parameters and return values

From `python-3.5` it can be used  for [Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)

Comment: My mind is thoroughly blown!

Comment: One good thing to add here is whether they alter the functionality of a program or are they only annotations? Like will your program throw an error if you don't follow the rules in the annotation?

Comment: Example would be great here inside the answer